# Why is autowiring required? What is the explanation of the concept of autowiring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Why is autowiring required? What is the explanation for the concept of autowiring?

`@autowired` annotation in [Spring Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework).

Comment: Who tells you so ridiculous truth?

Comment: @ vacuum... i am new to this framework.. i was referring some examples in every example autowire annotation is used.. so i thought its manadory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autowiring is not required, just convenient.

It means that if you have a property that requires an `InterfaceA` and a single bean has been declared in Spring that is of type `InterfaceA`, instead of using XML to manually "wire up" the relationship (setting a bean reference as a property of another), you can let Spring do the wiring for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common question for the beginners. As the beans are injected using [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (setter injections, constructor injections), why do we need auto-wiring? Auto-wiring also doing the same thing, right?

The answer is, it saves you from writing more code.

1. If **using an XML file**, using ***`autowire` attribute*** saves you from writing the **wiring code** in the bean definition.

   Please look at code below.

   Configuration code ***without Auto-wiring:***

   ```
    <bean id="employee" class="com.Employee">
        <property name="name" value="Dexter"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.EmployeeService">
        <property name="employee" ref="employee"></property>
    </bean>
   ```

   Configuration code ***with Auto-wiring:***

   ```
    <bean id="employee" class="com.Employee">
        <property name="name" value="Dexter"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.EmployeeService" autowire="byName" />
   ```

   Note that we did not have to write anything to refer property of EmployeeService, i.e., Employee. But still it was injected.  ***Autowiring makes the container to search the bean configurations and do the collaboration among beans, without the developer specifically mentioning these.***
2. If we **use annotation**, even we don’t have to write anything in XML files, including this `autoware="byName"`, etc. ***Simply `@Autowired` on bean's setter/field/constructor*** is sufficient.

Comment: I liked this explanation! A good example where it is shown how it was without autowire and with it.